# Can't hide back button inside my navigationbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, back-button

I am trying to hide my backbutton in the firstView after I logged into the application. I have this piece of code inside my ViewWillAppear.

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
```

But my back button will not dissapear.

any help ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these couple of lines , this will work out:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = TRUE;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work. Can it be a problem that there is a tabbarcontroller inside my navigationcontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom UIBarButtonItem as left bar button. That one you can try to hide or desing in a smooth way that it helps achieving what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide back button, than maybe you do not want to get back to previous screen. If this is the case, instead of pushing navigation controller show your view modally.
Otherwise do the following:

```
UIButton* myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
UIBarButtonItem* myBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
myButton.hidden = YES;
```